# Smooth horizontal scrolling of large background images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

at the website klangmanufaktur.de we have a horizontal scrolling design (on desktop screens). However, on some subpages there are large background images and scrolling is not smooth at all (when clicking the horizontal arrows):
[www.klangmanufaktur.de/impressionen/](http://www.klangmanufaktur.de/impressionen/)
This is especially true for Safari.

The images are loaded using  tags, but are changed to background images within a large  using DOM manipulation with jQuery. There are to issues:
1. No smooth scrolling
2. Background images load only when scrolled into the viewport, so for a short moment, the black background is visible

Here is the code for horizontal scrolling on arrow click:

```
   // horizontal scrolling on arrow click
$('.horizontal-arrow.right').click(function(){
    if($(window).innerWidth()>767) {
        var scrolled = false;
        $('.pagebox-inner').each(function(){
            if($(this).offset().left>window.pageXOffset + $(window).width() - $('header.site-header').outerWidth() && scrolled==false) {
                $('body,html').animate({ scrollLeft: $(this).offset().left - $('header.site-header').outerWidth() }, 2000, 'swing',function(){
                });
                scrolled=true;
            }
        });
    }
});

$('.horizontal-arrow.left').click(function(){
    if($(window).innerWidth()>767) {
        var scrolled = false;
        $($('.pagebox-inner').get().reverse()).each(function(){
            if($(this).offset().left<window.pageXOffset + $('header.site-header').outerWidth() && scrolled==false) {
                $('body,html').animate({ scrollLeft: $(this).offset().left - $('header.site-header').outerWidth() }, 2000, 'swing',function(){
                });
                scrolled=true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And here is the code for scrolling when a submenu link is clicked, like here:
[www.klangmanufaktur.de/restaurierung](http://www.klangmanufaktur.de/restaurierung/)

```
      // horizontal scrolling of anchor links
   $('nav.main-navigation li a').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('href')!=$(this).attr('href').replace('#','')) {
            $(this).click(function(){
                currentMainHash = window.location.hash;
                var linkUrlSplit = $(this).attr('href').split("#");
                var currElem = $('#post-'+linkUrlSplit[linkUrlSplit.length-1]);
                if(currElem) {
                    if($(window).innerWidth()>767) $('body,html').animate({ scrollLeft: currElem.offset().left - $('header.site-header').outerWidth() }, 2000,'swing',function(){ scrolled = false; });
                    else  $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: currElem.offset().top }, 2000,'swing',function(){
                        scrolled = false;
                        $(this).blur();
                    });
                }
                $('.currentLink').removeClass('currentLink');
                $(this).addClass('currentLink');
            });
        }
   });
```

Any suggestions how to resolve the "unsmooth scrolling" issue here? Is it maybe helpful do display the images as  elements instead of background images?

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards
joschi81

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using CSS transitions instead of jQuery.  The reason being is that CSS transitions are handled by the browser, rather than a 3rd party library.  You generally get better animations when the browser is handling and rendering them itself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I read about this solution before. However, I don't know how to implement this in my case: I have many <div>s next to each other horizontally. I see how to use css transitions, but how to move the whole content using CSS3 on button click?

Comment: It's quite simple once you get your head around it.  I'll do something basic on jsfiddle and post something that should help you.

Comment: Have a look at this... https://jsfiddle.net/h5tjcjvk/   The key thing is the `transition` property.  Once you add that then the movement is automatically animated.

Comment: This is a great help, thanks. It works perfectly in Firefox, but e.g. in Opera and Chrome, the transition gets "stuck" after approx. 1cm for a little moment and then it continues. Do you see this problem as well? I tried another version with the images loaded via <img> and not as background images: [jsfiddle.net/2qestqtn](https://jsfiddle.net/2qestqtn/), but same problem here.